# Problem with format in C# with DataGridView and TextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem with format in C#.
I have a DataGridView and a TextBox. In this datagridview, there is a column: the single price (format int).
I want sum every elements of single price's column and insert the result into this textbox, but Visual Studio gives me  a problem with format of string input ("Format of input's string is not correct").
this is the code than i used:

```
int TOT = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TOT = TOT + Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[6].ToString());
                }
                textBoxTot.Text = Convert.ToString(TOT);
```

Can you help me with this bad error?

UPDATE:
I think that the problem now is another. I can't find the methods of MySql.Data.MySqlClient library that it can give me the result of query.

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
            String sumQuery = "SELECT SUM(`prezzo`) FROM `fatturetemp`";
            command.CommandText = sumQuery;
            command.Connection = conn.getConnection();
            command.Parameters.Add("@prezzo", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = costo;
            conn.openConnection();
            conn.closeConnection();
```

How is the command that give me the result of sumQuery. If i find this command, i can take the result of query and paste in textbox

Comment: Why are you converting the value to a string first? What is the data type in column 7? Why wouldn't you directly cast to int (more likely decimal if it is a price).

Comment: BTW, likely you are getting that error on new row. Check if that row IsNewRow. (dataGridView3.Rows[I].IsNewRow)

Comment: Because without the .ToString, give me error. Data type of 7 column is int.

Comment: I HAVE UPDATE MY ANSWER. THE PROBLEM NOW IS ANOTHER. CAN YOU HELP ME?

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that you are first converting to a string and then to an int.

```
int TOT = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!dataGridView3.Rows[i].IsNewRow &&
  int.TryParse(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(), out int v))
       TOT += v;
}
textBoxTot.Text = TOT.ToString();
```

EDIT: Edited for your updated question. You shouldn't ask question inside a question buy anyway:

```
string sumQuery = "SELECT SUM(`prezzo`) FROM `fatturetemp`";
decimal total = 0M;
using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(" your connection string here "))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sumQuery, cn))
{
  cn.Open();
  total = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
  cn.Close();
}
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Comment: By "cast" did you mean "parse"? One wouldn't say (in c#) that they "cast" a string to an int

Comment: @CaiusJard, no I meant to say cast. You cast an object holding integer values as an example, rather than parse. Parsing is different, see the above example which Parse's a string to an int.

Comment: The way you choose to phrase, going straight from talking about "converting a string to an int" to "you'd do that with a cast" makes it sound like you're asserting a string can be cast to an int. I'm trying to get you to clarify that the cast should be done on the source. Your code didn't help clarify because it then mentioned parsing. Nowhere do you actually do any casting. Please make your code and your words agree, as it will make your answer more coherent and easy to understand, perhaps with two code samples (a casted and a parsed route)

Comment: @CaiusJard, no you are making that up. I said "Normally you would do that with a direct cast" because one would normally expect a binding to an integer object there. My code clearly shows that Parse is used with a string. I tell I found it weird converting to a string first.

Comment: I understand why you say that, but it's a really common pattern; an inexperienced developer is reading something out of a DGV Cell, and it's coming as `object` - you and I know it's an `int`, and we could say `(int)dgv[i, 6]` but someone somewhere will have told him "tostring it and parse it, because it'll work".. and it'll work if it's a string boxed as object, or int - another thing where the same kind of dev who will think it's OK to stuff data into a datagridview like`dgv[i,6].Value = "Hello"` will also not really care so much about datatypes (-> NumberFormatException anyone?)

Comment: But what I'm trying to say is your answer isn't really coherent; *I* can tell what you're talking about, but your first sentence is talking about `int->tostring->toint`, then your second sentence talks about cast, which given that you just been talking about `tostring->toint` means it reads weird, then immediately after talking about cast, you write some code *that doesn't do any casting* - so it's all a bit confused really. It would be better if you throw that comment about casting away,cos only someone who understands *int boxed as object* will get you(and they wont make this mistake,OP did)

Comment: This isn't about lack of English anything; your English will forever be a million times better than my Turkish and huge props to you for that - the entire and only reason we can communicate is for all your hard work and I do appreciate it. This is just about trying to tell you how the answer reads to a third party (me) and how it could be a bit confusing to a new dev, that you talk about casting, but don't do any casting..

Comment: OK to satisfy you I will delete "cast" :) God forgive me. BTW I wouldn't suggest the way you showed, which is another odd way of doing it. would you really keep the total in a new column if you were doing this with pen & paper and update on each change?

Comment: I could talk at some length about the point you raise, but I'll save it for another day. This is one of the ways Microsoft intended it to be. I accept your point as valid.

Comment: @CaiusJard,  Microsoft is the one to be accused :) OK.

Comment: I try to solve with you route but the output on textBox is always 0

Answer (score 0):

If your datagridview is showing a datatable (I.e. your data is stored in a datatable) you can add a DataColumn to the datatable whose `.Expression` property is set to the string `"SUM([Price])"`, where *Price* is the name of your numeric datatyped column holding the price info.

Now every row in the table will have the sum of the prices (the same value over and over again), so if you want to databind your textBox to this new column then it will always show the sum no matter which row is the current row (because all rows have the same value). It will also auto update without you having to do anything!

And if you're not using databinding to a datatable, I recommend that you do do it, because it represents good MVC practice of keeping your data in one thing (DataTable) and showing it in another (DataGridView) and keeping these concerns separate

It would look something like this, as a quick example:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("CalculatedTotal", typeof(int)).Expression = "SUM([Price])";
        dt.Rows.Add("Apples", 100);
        dt.Rows.Add("Oranges", 200);

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dt;

        WhateverDataGridView.DataSource = bs;
        totalTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "CalculatedTotal", true));
```

Here we have a data model (the datatable) where we keep our data. It has a couple of things we can set directly, and an third column that calculates based on the existing prices in all the table. If you look at this in the datagridview (assuming you have autogeneratecolumns turned on) you'll see that both rows have 300 for the `CalculatedTotal`, but they have individual amounts for price. There is a device called a BindingSource that sits between the datatable and the UI controls; you don't have to have one but it makes certain things easier regards updating controls when the data changes, and it maintains a concept of "current" - essentially whatever the current row is you're looking at in the datagridview; it all helps to avoid having to ask the DGV for anything - we just let the user type into the DGV, and it shows the data out of the datatable. All our dealings can be with the datatable directly - if you wrote a button to loop through the table and double all the prices, the controls in the UI would just reflect the change automatically. The textbox is connected to the `CalculatedValue` column via databinding; whatever the current row is, the textbox will show the `CalculatedValue`. Because the `CalculatedValue` column has the same value on every row, and they always all update if any price changes, the total textbox will always show the total. Add another textbox bound to Name to see what I mean; as you click around the grid and select different rows to be the "Current" row, the Name will change but the total does not. In truth it is actually changing in the same way that Name is, it's just that because the actual numeric value is the same on every row the contents of the textbox *look* like they don't change

Comment: He didn't say a word about the datasource, and also he didn't want to show it in a new column but in a textbox. If the column doesn't have numeric data, such an expression wouldn't even  work.

Comment: I know (and I said so, did I not?); this is how it should be done; i'm fixing the X in his XY problem - you're fixing the Y

Comment: :) It is how "you" do it, not how it should be done. And BTW you didn't, you later edited to say so.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that you'd get many experienced developers to agree that pushing data boxed as objects in and out of a DataGridView directly is the way anything should be done. Most of them will encourage people to keep their data in some kind of dedicated model and manipulate it there, not drag it out of the Ui control that happens to be showing it. Re the crossing over of edit timings; I use the mobile site which is much less "live" than the full site; I can assure you I was unaware of your comment at the time I made the edit to clarify what Price was...

Comment: How could you reason the otherwise? Where did I say use boxed?

Comment: I HAVE UPDATE MY ANSWER. THE PROBLEM NOW IS ANOTHER. CAN YOU HELP ME?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I think that the problem now is another. I can't find the methods of MySql.Data.MySqlClient library that it can give me the result of query.

```
public string sommaFattura(String costo)
        {
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
                String sumQuery = "SELECT SUM(`prezzo`) FROM `fatturetemp`";
                command.CommandText = sumQuery;
                command.Connection = conn.getConnection();
                command.Parameters.Add("@prezzo", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = costo;
                conn.openConnection();
                conn.closeConnection();
}
```

How is the command that give me the result of sumQuery. If i find this command, i can take the result of query and paste in textbox